# Airflow on_success_callback() does not run

Tags: airflow

I am running a pipeline using Airflow which contains multiple Bash Operators to be executed.
Each operator has `on_failure_callback` and `on_success_callback` attributes that call a function to send an email with the status of the task (success/fail) and uploads generated log file from a directory to hdfs. The following code snippets shows a sample of the operator I am using and the callable function.

- **Bash Operator**:

> op = BashOperator(
>              task_id='test_op', 
>              bash_command='python3 run.py'  , 
>              on_failure_callback=fail_email,
>              on_success_callback = success_email,
>              retries=3,
>              dag=dag)

- **success_email**:

> ```
> def success_email(contextDict,**kwargs):
>     """Send custom email alerts."""
>
>     # email title.
>     title = "Task {} SUCCEEDED. Execution date: {}".format(contextDict['task'].task_id, contextDict['execution_date'])
>
>
>     # email contents
>     body = """
>
>          <br>
>          The correspondent log file:
>          <br>
>          {}
>           """.format(hdfs_log)
>
>     print("Uploading log to hdfs")
>     subprocess.check_call(["hdfs", "dfs", "-mkdir", "-p", hdfs_log_folder])
>     subprocess.check_call(["hdfs", "dfs", "-put", local_log, hdfs_log])
>     send_email('email@domain.com', title, html_content=body)
> ```

The `success_callback` always fails when calling the hdfs commands and gives the following error:

```
[2018-12-28 09:13:29,727] INFO - Uploading log to hdfs

[2018-12-28 09:13:30,344] INFO - [2018-12-28 09:13:30,342] WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to success. Taking the poison pill.

[2018-12-28 09:13:30,381] INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 11515
[2018-12-28 09:13:30,382] ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2018-12-28 09:13:30,382] INFO - Sending SIGTERM signal to bash process group
[2018-12-28 09:13:30,390] ERROR - Failed when executing success callback
[2018-12-28 09:13:30,390] ERROR - [Errno 3] No such process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hadoop/airflow/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1687, in _run_raw_task
    task.on_success_callback(context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/Appl_FUMA.py", line 139, in success_email
    subprocess.check_call(["hdfs", "dfs", "-mkdir", "-p", hdfs_log_folder])
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 286, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 269, in call
    return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1457, in wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1404, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
  File "/opt/hadoop/airflow/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1611, in signal_handler
    task_copy.on_kill()
  File "/opt/hadoop/airflow/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 125, in on_kill
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(self.sp.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] No such process
[2018-12-28 09:13:30,514] INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=11515 (terminated)) (11515) terminated with exit code 0
[2018-12-28 09:13:30,514] INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=20649 (terminated)) (20649) terminated with exit code None
[2018-12-28 09:13:30,514] INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=11530 (terminated)) (11530) terminated with exit code None
[2018-12-28 09:13:30,515] INFO - [2018-12-28 09:13:30,515] INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

However, it manages to send emails (sometimes) when I comment out the two lines of subprocesses. 
Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: how did u resolve?